# Register com dll for use by vba

Tags: visual-studio, com

I have a very basic question. I have developed a com dll to be used from Access vba. Works great on my development machine. On a test machine I get the

```
"error -2147024894 (80070002) Automation Error
System can't find the specified file"
```

msg when I run the Access application.

When in design view the dll is referenced and all the objects and properties show up in the vba ide.

I am wondering if I am using the wrong regasm to register the dll? I develop on a 64 bit machine using VS 2010.

I compile the dll to run on x86 in Framework 3.5. Should I use the framework v2. o.50727 or Framework\v4.0.30319 to register the dll. Not clear to me what the difference is. Is the version used determined by the development version of VS or the .NET version you compile in? Is one used for 32 bit and the other for 64 bit?

I have been fighting this for 2 days and have made some headway but can't get the Access routines to actually set an instance of the dll in runtime.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: not sure how to edit after submiting.

Comment: If you're signed in with the same account, there's an edit link immediately below the tags in your question. :) While you edit, you can get an immediate WYSIWYG preview in the area right below where you're typing your question, so you can see what it will look like when you submit it. There's also help available by clicking the orange question mark immediately above the top right corner of the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling under v3.5, you should use that regasm. However, I think you might need to add the /tlb and /codebase switches  to generate the type library that you can use in vba apps. You can then ref the .tlb file and you should be golden.

Comment: I just unregistered the dll. Then moved to new location. Re-registered using "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\Users\Doug\Documents\AccessProjects\VROM\dll\eBayListing.dll /tlb:eBayListing.tlb \codebase" Access imediately found it when went back to the references. All code compiles, but I still get the 'can't find the specified file' error when running.

Comment: That is it. I had the codebase flag backwards. When I read my last I noticed the typo. Using the v2.0.50727 version of regasm with /codebase did the trick. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your COM dll using `regsvr32` for referencing it from VBA.

Answer (score -2):

VBA uses COM DLLs. You would have to use C++, not the .Net framework.

Comment: Possibly I wasn't clear. I am referencing my dll from vba. The dll works fine with vba on my development machine. The issue appears to be registering it properly on other machines so it can be used there.

Comment: This is just wrong. There's no requirement to write COM in C++ (Delphi isn't C++ and produces COM DLLs that are usable in VBA), and `VSTO` uses .NET.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question properly. Try running depends.exe on the COM DLL on the target machine. That will flag any missing dependencies. 80070002 is file not found.